# Conditional statements in Python3

Tags: python-3.x

With the given code, for the input 2100 the output should be False. But the function is returning True

```
def is_leap(year):
    if (year%4==0 & year%100==0 & year%400==0):
        leap = True
    else:
        leap = False

    # Write your logic here

    return leap

year = int(input())
print(is_leap(year))
```

When I change the code to (change in the conditional structure: `(year%4==0 & year%100==0 & year%400==0)` to `((year%4==0 & year%100==0) & (year%400==0))`): It is returning False (which is expected). Why is that happening?

```
def is_leap(year):
    if ((year%4==0 & year%100==0) & (year%400==0)):
        leap = True
    else:
        leap = False

    # Write your logic here

    return leap

year = int(input())
print(is_leap(year))
```

Comment: `&` is a bitwise AND. You probably meant to do `and`, which is a logical AND.

Comment: @TedKleinBergman `and` is and not `&&`

Comment: Note that  ``&`` *can* be used here, but its precedence differs from ``and``. Also, ``and`` has the benefit of short-circuiting (aka being faster in many cases). Use ``((year%4==0) & (year%100==0) & (year%400==0))`` if you really want to. Finally, don't use ``if``-``else`` to compute a boolean. You can directly return the result, e.g. ``return year%4==0 and year%100==0 and year%400==0``.

Answer (score 0):

`&` is bitwise and whereas `and` is logical and.

False evaluates to 0 and True to 1. Therefore, it is legal to do bitwise and boolean operators, but might not result in the correct answer.